# How to use aliases with auto completion in oh-my-zsh?

Tags: osx, zsh, alias, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I'm using zsh on MacOS El Capitan. I'm wondering how auto completion has to be parameterized to resolve aliases as well.
When I used bash, my `.bash_profile` contained the following:

```
alias mdb "mongo -uadmin -pXXX --authenticationDatabase admin --host "
complete -W "$HOSTNAMES" mdb
```

`HOSTNAMES` is a list of over 4000 FQDN's.
Doing so I could type `mdb someHost`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> to see a list with all hosts beginning with `someHost`. Once the right host selected, the command got completed to `mongo -uadmin -pXXX --authenticationDatabase admin --host someHostFoo`.

Right now, I want to use oh-my-zsh so I copied the above mentioned lines in my `.zshrc` file. However, when the hostname list exceeds round about 1500 entries, auto completion becomes **very** slow. For that reason I replaced `complete -W "$HOSTNAMES" mdb` with `compctl -c "$HOSTNAMES" mdb` in my `.zshrc` file. However, this wont work, even if I set `setopt complete_aliases` in my `.zshrc`.
Today I [read](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org) that one should better write completion functions for commands since `compctl` is deprecated. I came up with this but this will only suggest host names after having typed `mdb hosts`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> when `$HOSTNAMES` contains very few host names:

```
#compdef mongo mdb
#autoload


_mongo_hosts(){
  mhosts=$HOSTNAMES
}

local -a _1st_arguments
_1st_arguments=(
  "--host:host to be connected to"
)

local expl
local -a mhosts

if (( CURRENT == 2 )); then
  _describe -t commands "mongo subcommand" _1st_arguments
  return
fi

case "$words[2]" in
    hosts)
      _mongo_hosts
      _wanted mhosts expl 'known hosts' compadd -a mhosts ;;
esac
```

Furthermore, by this approach, `mdb` is not yet replaced by `mongo -uadmin -pXXX --authenticationDatabase admin --host`.

**Follow up**

I discarded the above shown `compdef` approach. My current workaround is to add the following two lines to my `.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand_alias _complete _ignored
zstyle ':completion:*:(ssh|scp|sftp|host):*' hosts $HOSTNAMES
```

The first line is to expand aliases as well, here my alias `mdb`.

The second line allows to cycle through all host names when commands like `ssh`, `scp`, `sftp` or `host` are used. The same could be achieved by this line:

```
_hosts() {compadd $(echo $HOSTNAMES | tr "\n" " ")}
```

So with this approach, I have to type first `ssh someHost`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>, choose the host and then replace `ssh` by `mdb` so it will complete to `mongo -uadmin -pXXX --authenticationDatabase admin --host someHostFoo`

This works but isn't perfect. I'd prefer to have the same auto completion experience I had using bash, implemented by the first shown two lines here in my question. How to achieve this with zsh and and more than 4000 host names?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which works exactly as I wanted. Only the following three lines are required in `.zshrc`:

```
mdb() {mongo -uadmin -pXXX --authenticationDatabase admin --host "$@"}
compctl -k "($(echo $HOSTNAMES))" mdb
zstyle ':completion:*:(ssh|scp|sftp|host):*' hosts $(echo $HOSTNAMES)
```

The function `mdb()` replaces my former alias `mdb`. 
The `compctl` command completes functions like `mdb` with the array of `$HOSTNAMES`.
The `zstyle` instruction  completes commands like `ssh`, `scp`, `sftp` and `host` with the array of `$HOSTNAMES`.